# What is "Extensible" about XHTML?

Tags: xhtml

Why is XHTML called "eXtensible" (the `X` in `XHTML`)? Can we, as individual web developers actually extend it?

What separates it from ordinary HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly, things have moved on somewhat, and XHTML isn't really a thing anymore. HTML5 isn't parsed as XML, and XHTML 2.0 was of course cancelled.

Despite that, it's possible to use XHTML if you use the `application/xhtml+xml` mimetype, just be aware of the various shortcomings of that (any error = yellow screen of death, older IEs don't render anything at all).

For a new project, use the HTML5 doctype and serve as `text/html`. XHTML can be considered as a failure for many reasons.

Anyway, with XHTML you can do things like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://example.com/my-xhtml-custom.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:custom="http://example.com/" xml:lang='en-US'>
```

then copy http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd and edit it how you like, and put it where we referenced earlier.

The w3c have a lot to say about this, specifically:

> Don't do this! Documents need to have a meaning as well as correct
>   syntax. SGML and XML only define syntax. HTML and XHTML define
>   meaning. If you add elements that aren't defined by a standard, only
>   you yourself know what they mean. And in 20 or 50 years, even you may
>   not know it anymore…
>
> Of course, you can experiment, for example to work on future Web
>   formats, but other than that you should not use proprietary elements.

Nowadays, we thankfully have HTML5 which dropped all this XML stuff (no one was using it and it adds a lot of complexity). It's not extensible in the same way, but that's probably a good thing!

Comment: `You can do things like this:

<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://example.com/my-xhtml-custom.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:custom="http://example.com/" xml:lang='en-US'>
then copy http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd and edit it how you like, and put it where we referenced earlier`  
But I thought those "links"/"references" used as namespaces didn't actually link to anything. (See my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201678/in-dtds-why-are-namespaces-given-as-a-url))

Comment: They don't have to, but it is valid to have something there to assist someone trying to understand what you are doing. It's all mad really as browsers are more than happy to allow you to make up tags whenever you like anyway.

Comment: HTML5 does not drop the XML stuff. XHTML is a fully integrated serlalization of HTML5.

Comment: I guess I mean that the parser isn't an XML one in the way the `application/xhtml+xml` parser was.