# Is there such thing called "virtual URL" for a namespace?

Tags: xsd, wsdl, xml-namespaces

One of the web services I inherited in my current job contains a WSDL schema with the following namespace definition:

```
<xs:schema 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
  xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:mns="http://my.example.com/sumproj/msgs.xsd" 
  xmlns:tns="http://my.example.com/sumproj" 
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
  targetNamespace="http://my.example.com/sumproj/msgs.xsd" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

All of the external URLs listed above can be accessed through a web browser, but the internal ones (my.example.com domain) only produce a "Not Found" error:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /sumproj/msgs.xsd was not found on this server.

Since the person to ask about why certain things are implemented the way they are has left, I am wondering whether this is a bug or a feature:

- Has the authoring developer intended to place the namespace XSD on that http://my.example.com server and simply didn't get to implementing it?
- Or is it some type of security feature in which the URL is only accessible by the web service through a config XML, effectively defining this URL as virtual when it actually access localhost or similar?

If the latter, *how* does this work and *where* I can learn more about it?

(**Note:** example.com above is only used for illustration, I can't really disclose my employer's internal URL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Has the authoring developer intended to place the namespace XSD on that http://my.example.com server and simply didn't get to implementing it?*

That's possible, but not certain; without reading the developer's mind no firm answer is possible.  A rational developer might do it either way -- even if many people including me would say it's better practice and more rational to put namespace documentation (possibly in the form of a schema document, possibly in the form of a RDDL document, possibly in another form) at the namespace URI.

*Or is it some type of security feature in which the URL is only accessible by the web service through a config XML, effectively defining this URL as virtual when it actually access localhost or similar?*

Not impossible, but this is not a design technique that seems to be widely documented. (At least, there's at least one XML geek who's never heard it suggested.)  So I would guess the answer is:  probably not the original author's intent.

*Can you point me to an authoritative source where I can read about this?*

The authoritative source for XML namespaces are the documents "[Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/)" and "[Namespaces in XML 1.1 (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/)", edited by Tim Bray et al. and published by the World Wide Web Consortium in 2009 and 2006, respectively.

It's difficult to prove a negative concisely, but examination of the spec should make clear that it imposes no requirement that URIs used as namespace names should be dereferenceable.  Section 2.1 says "An XML namespace is identified by a URI reference [RFC3986]" but nothing in the spec requires that namespace names be dereferenced.  Section 2.3 defines the process of namespace-name matching as a test for string identity and points out that this means that equivalent forms of the same URI (e.g. `http://www.example.org/wine` and `http://www.Example.org/wine`) do not count as equal for purpose of namespace-name matching.  This would make no sense at all if namespace processors were required to dereference namespace names.

The W3C Technical Architecture Group (TAG) discusses this complex of questions from a higher-level point of view in it document [Architecture of the World Wide Web, Volume One](http://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/).  See in particular

- section 3.5 (which enunciates the principle that "Reference does not imply dereference": "An application developer or specification author SHOULD NOT require networked retrieval of representations each time they are referenced."
- section 4.5.3 on XML namespaces
- section 4.5.4 on namespace documents (which the TAG recommends)

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201678/in-dtds-why-are-namespaces-given-as-a-url) (and my answer to it).

*if a name space URL does point to a resource, does this necessarily imply that the WSDL schema must consult with it at runtime?*

No.  WSDL can impose extra rules on the use of namespace names in WSDL documents, but the document fragment you quote is from an XSD schema document.  The XSD spec does not require that namespace names be dereferenced (although it does suggest it as one possible strategy for locating XSD schema documents for use in a validation episode).

*If the answer is no, can it consult with it at runtime? or is it only for human reading?*

It is not forbidden for processors to dereference namespace name, but some authorities discourage it.  When widely deployed software dereferences namespace names every time it runs, or every time it reads an XML document, the result can be excessive and unnecessary network traffic.  W3C has been suffering under such unnecessary traffic for some years and now serves all schemas at artificially slow rates in order to persuade users to complain to their software vendors.  (See Ted Guild's [blog post](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/) of 2008 for details.)

Comment: I could not have asked for an answer more detailed than this, referring to each and every one of my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

XML namespaces are URIs (Uniform Resource Identifiers) which are intended to distinguish the author's meaning of the element 'book', say, from the meaning of the element 'book' as it might appear in any other XML document.

If I choose a namespace for my schema, I need to be absolutely sure it won't be the same as a namespace that anyone else might choose. In order to make sure that this clashing won't happen, authors usually make their namespaces begin with a domain name owned by them. This makes them look like URLs, but there is no requirement actually to make the namespace URI actually point at a useful resource, or indeed anything at all. Helpful organisations, like the w3c, actually post resources at these URIs, which is why the external namespaces in the document above worked.

Comment: The most important piece of information I read in your answer is that **"there is no requirement actually to make the namespace URI actually point at a useful resource, or indeed anything at all."** Can you point me to an authoritative source where I can read about this? (I tried to find this in `w3.org` but couldn't) Also, if a name space URL *does* point to a resource, does this necessarily imply that the WSDL schema **must** consult with it at runtime? If the answer is no, **can** it consult with it at runtime? or is it only for human reading? Thanks +1 for now.

Comment: On [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) on w3schools it says 'The namespace URI is not used by the parser to look up information.' Anyway, as there is no standard for what should be at the URL, it wouldn't know what to do do with the resource if it were to download anything. The [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) on the matter references [this 12-year-old document](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/oreilly/xml/news/xmlnut2_0201.html) which proposes a standard that hasn't been adopted.